# Business pack gridview - Validation and form editing

Tags: gridview, dotvvm

I am using dotvvm for a line of business application and need to use the gridview extensively and have a few issues I need resolved.

What is the recommended approach for validating when using inline inserting and editing?  I can't seem to display any validation errors. I need it to work for both data annotations and custom validation.

Secondly, is there anyway I can use form editing in the gridview instead of inline? I am thinking something like the editform or popupeditform in devexpress. https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditModes.aspx

```
<div Validation.Target="{value: Bloods}" Validator.InvalidCssClass="has-error" Validator.SetToolTipText="true">
    <bp:GridView DataSource="{value: Bloods}" InlineEditMode="SingleRow" AllowInlineInsert="true" class="page-grid">
        <Columns>
            <bp:GridViewComboBoxColumn Validation.Enabled="true" Validator.Value="{value: BloodProductID}" Value="{value: BloodProductID}" DataSource="{value: ProductList }" ItemValueBinding="{value: Value}" ItemTextBinding="{value: Text}" HeaderText="Product" />
            <bp:GridViewTextColumn Value="{value: Comments}" HeaderText="Comments" />
            <bp:GridViewTemplateColumn>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <dot:LinkButton Validation.Enabled="false" Click="{command: _parent.Bloods.RowEditOptions.EditRowId = rowID}">
                        <bs:Icon Type="pencil" />
                    </dot:LinkButton>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <InsertTemplate>
                    <bp:Button Text="Save"
                               Type="Success"
                               Click="{command: _parent.SaveNewBlood()}"
                               Visible="{value: _parent.IsBloodInserting}"
                               Validation.Target={value: _this} />
                    <bp:Button Text="Cancel"
                               Type="Danger"
                               Click="{command: _parent.CancelInsertBlood()}"
                               Visible="{value: _parent.IsBloodInserting}"
                               Validation.Enabled="false" />
                </InsertTemplate>
                <EditTemplate>
                    <bp:Button Text="Save" Type="Success" Click="{command: _parent.UpdateBlood(_this)}" Validation.Target={value: _this} />
                    <bp:Button Text="Cancel" Type="Danger" Click="{command: _parent.CancelEditBlood()}" Validation.Enabled="false" />
                </EditTemplate>
            </bp:GridViewTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No bloods found.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
       

    </bp:GridView>
</div>
    <br />
    <bp:Button Text="Add Blood"
               Click="{command: InsertBlood()}"
               Visible="{value: !IsBloodInserting}"
               Validation.Enabled="false" />
    <bp:DataPager DataSet="{value: Bloods}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making an edit form inside GridView, you can use the `RowDetailTemplate`.

About the validation in the row editing and inserting, it should work automatically if you have set `Validator.InvalidCssClass` or a similar property anywhere on a parent element - this will tell DotVVM how the validation errors should be visualized.
Also, if you are using the `ValidationSummary` control, make sure to set `IncludeErrorsFromChildren=true` to display the errors from child objects (elements of the DataSource collection).

The ideal way is then set `Validation.Target={value: _this}` to all the buttons in the edit form/row so the validation errors are being checked only in the currently edited item.

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there any example using RowDetailTemplate, I havn't been able to get it to show.

Comment: Ahh, have finally worked it out, the issue was resolved as soon as i added BusinessPack.AllowAutoValidation="true"